# How to write Jquery click event in a table

Tags: jquery

Here i want  Bind Id value to its click Event.When i click on Edit link its Hit Hello function

```
$('#Btn2').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:44509/api/Stored/GetEmployee",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered');
                var $header = $('<thead/>').html('<tr><th>EmpId</th<th>Action</th></tr>');
                $table.append($header);
                $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));              
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='http://localhost:44509/api/Stored/EditEmp' click='Hello()'" + value.Emp_Id + ">Edited</a>"))
                    $table.append($row);
                });
                $('#Div1').html($table);
            }
        })
    })

    $('#Hello').click(function () {
        alert();
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meybe this:

```
$('#Btn2').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:44509/api/Stored/GetEmployee",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered');
                var $header = $('<thead/>').html('<tr><th>EmpId</th<th>Action</th></tr>');
                $table.append($header);
                $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));              
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='http://localhost:44509/api/Stored/EditEmp' onClick='Hello(\'"+value.Emp_Id+"\');'>Edited</a>"))
                    $table.append($row);
                });
                $('#Div1').html($table);
            }
        })
    })

    function Hello (_in) {
        alert(_in);
    })
```